# Calculate bounding box for OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap

Is possible to get bounding box from coordinates (latitude, longitude), zoom level and size (screen)? I found only [calculating bounding box from tile](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Tile_bounding_box). I need it, because OpenStreetMap accept only bbox in export mode. I dont have any experience with this, so I will be glad for any advice. Thanks.

**Edit:**

Sorry, I was describe it wrong. I write something like this:

(pseudocode)
`

```
x = getX(longitude, zoom); //X Tile - return 41870
y = getY(latitude, zoom); //Y Tile - return 22226
north = getXToLongitude(x, zoom); //return 49.998779 
south = getXToLongitude(x + 1, zoom); //return 50.004272
west = getYToLatitude(y, zoom); //return 49.997078 
east = getYToLatitude(y + 1, zoom); //return 50.000609
```

`

But this is very inaccurate and and shifts the center of the 100 m.

Comment: How should that be possible? The visible bounding box on a specific zoom level depends on the browser window size.

Comment: Did you already take a look at [these tools](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Tools)?

Comment: It isn't as easy as you think first time. Because earth is nearly a sphere distance will be different in different latitudes. In small areas, the difference will be small but smaller zoom levels you will get quite big difference. If you want to avoid this, you should play with the surface formula of a sphere.

Comment: Thanks for the tools, its very helpfull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. I've had a similar problem, so I've written it up. Like this:

```
use Math::Trig;

sub getTileNumber {
    my ($lat,$lon,$zoom) = @_;
    my $xtile = int( ($lon+180)/360 * 2**$zoom ) ;
    my $ytile = int( (1 - log(tan(deg2rad($lat)) + sec(deg2rad($lat)))/pi)/2 * 2**$zoom ) ;
    return ($xtile, $ytile);
}

sub getLonLat {
    my ($xtile, $ytile, $zoom) = @_;
    my $n = 2 ** $zoom;
    my $lon_deg = $xtile / $n * 360.0 - 180.0;
    my $lat_deg = rad2deg(atan(sinh(pi * (1 - 2 * $ytile / $n))));
    return ($lon_deg, $lat_deg);
}

# convert from permalink OSM format like:
# http://www.openstreetmap.org/?lat=43.731049999999996&lon=15.79375&zoom=13&layers=M
# to OSM "Export" iframe embedded bbox format like:
# http://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=15.7444,43.708,15.8431,43.7541&layer=mapnik

sub LonLat_to_bbox {
    my ($lat, $lon, $zoom) = @_;

    my $width = 425; my $height = 350;  # note: must modify this to match your embed map width/height in pixels
    my $tile_size = 256;

    my ($xtile, $ytile) = getTileNumber ($lat, $lon, $zoom);

    my $xtile_s = ($xtile * $tile_size - $width/2) / $tile_size;
    my $ytile_s = ($ytile * $tile_size - $height/2) / $tile_size;
    my $xtile_e = ($xtile * $tile_size + $width/2) / $tile_size;
    my $ytile_e = ($ytile * $tile_size + $height/2) / $tile_size;

    my ($lon_s, $lat_s) = getLonLat($xtile_s, $ytile_s, $zoom);
    my ($lon_e, $lat_e) = getLonLat($xtile_e, $ytile_e, $zoom);

    my $bbox = "$lon_s,$lat_s,$lon_e,$lat_e";
    return $bbox;
}
```

I've also added this info to [OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Lon..2Flat._to_bbox), so it will be easier to find in the future...

Comment: Is there any way to calculate BBOX not using getTileNumber function?

Comment: @unibasil I forgot to include that function. I've updated answer now, is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement Angular component for OSM embedding, based on code samples from [OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames). It turned out to be pretty hard. :(

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-osm',
  templateUrl: './osm.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./osm.component.scss']
})
export class OsmComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() latitude: number;
  @Input() longitude: number;
  @Input() zoom: number;

  public iframeSrc;
  public extMapSrc;

  constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const bbox = this.boundaryBox(this.latitude, this.longitude, 1100, 400, 16);
    this.iframeSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
      `https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html` +
      `?bbox=${bbox.join(',')}` +
      `&layer=mapnik` +
      `&marker=${this.latitude},${this.longitude}`
    );
    this.extMapSrc = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(
      `https://www.openstreetmap.org/` +
      `?mlat=${this.latitude}&mlon=${this.longitude}` +
      `#map=17/${this.latitude}/${this.longitude}`
    );
  }

  lonToTile(lon: number, zoom: number): number {
    return (Math.floor((lon + 180) / 360 * Math.pow(2, zoom)));
  }

  latToTile(lat: number, zoom: number): number {
    return Math.floor(
      (1 - Math.log(
        Math.tan(lat * Math.PI / 180) + 1 / Math.cos(lat * Math.PI / 180)
      ) / Math.PI) / 2 * Math.pow(2, zoom)
    );
  }

  tileToLon(x: number, zoom: number): number {
    return (x / Math.pow(2, zoom) * 360 - 180);
  }

  tileToLat(y: number, zoom: number): number {
    const n = Math.PI - 2 * Math.PI * y / Math.pow(2, zoom);
    return (180 / Math.PI * Math.atan(0.5 * (Math.exp(n) - Math.exp(-n))));
  }

  boundaryBox(
    lat: number,
    lon: number,
    width: number = 1110,
    height: number = 400,
    zoom: number = 17,
  ) {
    const tileSize = 256;

    const lonTile = this.lonToTile(lon, zoom);
    const latTile = this.latToTile(lat, zoom);

    const minLonTile = (lonTile * tileSize - width / 2) / tileSize;
    const minLatTile = (latTile * tileSize - height / 2) / tileSize;
    const maxLonTile = (lonTile * tileSize + width / 2) / tileSize;
    const maxLatTile = (latTile * tileSize + height / 2) / tileSize;

    const minLon = this.tileToLon(minLonTile, zoom);
    const minLat = this.tileToLat(minLatTile, zoom);
    const maxLon = this.tileToLon(maxLonTile, zoom);
    const maxLat = this.tileToLat(maxLatTile, zoom);

    return [minLon, minLat, maxLon, maxLat];
  }

}
```

It (kind of) works, though map positioning for some reason is not exactly correct.